# Visual Studio 2013 RTM Setup Failed - The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013

[Visual Studio 2013 released to web!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/10/17/visual-studio-2013-released-to-web.aspx)

[Top things web developers should know about the Visual Studio 2013 release](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2013/10/17/top-things-web-developers-should-know-about-the-visual-studio-2013-release.aspx)

System Requirements:

**Supported operating systems**

> Windows 7 SP1 (x86 and x64)
>
> Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
>
> Windows 8.1 (x86 and x64)
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
>
> Windows Server 2012 (x64)
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 (x64)

**Required components**

> Internet Explorer 10

**Hardware requirements**

> 1.6 GHz or faster processor
>
> 1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
>
> 10 GB of available hard disk space
>
> 5400 RPM hard disk drive
>
> DirectX 9-capable video card that runs at 1024 x 768 or higher display
>   resolution

Source: [Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/2013-editions#d-ultimate)

I'm trying to install VS 2013 Ultimate on top of VS 2013 RC and the following error messages are preventing the installation.

[image]

> The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by
>   the specified trust provider.

The failed components are:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 VsGraphics Helper
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Core Libraries
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Libraries
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Libraries
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 ARM Libraries
>
> Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Preview Object Model (x64)
>
> Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Preview Object Model Language
>   Pack (x64) - ENU
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview Multi-Targeting Pack (ENU)
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview Multi-Targeting Pack for
>   Windows Store Apps (ENU)
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview Multi-Targeting Pack Language
>   Pack - enu

This error means that Windows does not recognize the input file as something it is able to affix a digital signature on.

**Possible workaround**

Using **SetReg.exe** [Set Registry Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zaf80x7(v=vs.80).aspx) to disable Certificate Revocation List checking.

```
setreg 3 FALSE 
setreg 9 FALSE
```

Reference: [Another Possible Workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/12/11/another-possible-workaround-for-error-1330.aspx)

I can try the workaround above to sort the problem, but i was in belief that VS 2013 RC can be easily updated?

> VS 2013 can be installed side by side with previous versions of Visual
>   Studio or, if you have a VS 2013 pre-release, it can be installed
>   straight over  top of the pre-release.

Source: [Visual Studio 2013 RTM Available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/10/17/visual-studio-2013-rtm-available.aspx)

**UPDATE**

I've tried using web installer or downloading ISO image again, with no success, as possible solutions in related sources.

**RELATED**

1. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/791407/visual-studio-2013-preview-installation-fails-on-windows-8-1-preview
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/01d682c1-5f2b-450e-b902-e36f904c95bf/vs-express-2013-at-surface
3. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe3d5411-b601-425e-bf44-8cf5cd00f7af/visual-studio-2013-setup-failed-when-installing-on-windows-81-preview?forum=vssetup
4. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10cce939-b06e-4406-ab9a-36bbbddd342e/setup-failed-vs-2013-pro-beta-on-windows-81-pro-x64-beta-?prof=required

Comment: I cannot find this tool on my system.  Is there a way to set this in the registry itself?

Comment: @antman1p: The tool can be downloaded from "source" mentioned in the question.
To set directly in registry via regedit, go to `"HKEY_USER\[UNIQUE USER SID VALUE]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing"`. Then [modify value](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e37970f-0e6f-4253-a41b-721f457b8059/wintrust-software-publishing-state-values?forum=win10itprosecurity) of `"State"` eg. add flag WTPF_IGNOREREVOKATION would change 0x00023C00 -> 0x00023e00 (same as `setreg -q 3 FALSE`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to [Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-ultimate)

then choose **Web Installer** *(the first download option)*

[image]

If you have already tried installing VS 2013 using ISO Installer **you must reboot** before trying the Web Installer.

[image]

Comment: FWIW: I did not have to reboot between failed ISO-install and successful webinstaller-installer.

Comment: I was getting failed installation of VS 2013 Professional RTM ISO. The web installer installed without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify whether you have completely downloaded installer, in case if you are using ISO file. I've checked my own with the same problem, and it was broken. Sha hash was different.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while installing RTM version. I replaced the files from the RC version I had downloaded earlier. This is what I did to fix the issue

- Uninstall the failed version of 2013 from control panel -> Uninstall programs
- Restart the computer
- Extract the files from the ISO to a local folder
- Replace the the folder "Packages/vsGragphics Helper..." with the copy from RC version ISO.
- Re-run the setup again from local folder.

Comment: Is there somewhere one can Download this vsGraphics folder? I need to finish installation, but can't download another 2.8gig. How big is this vsGraphics folder please? Is it just the cab64_1 and vsgraphics_helperbits files in there?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can cause this error is if the setup files have not been successfully extracted from the ISO.  In the case I've just dealt with, a number of setup files were 0 bytes in length.

The problem can be worked around by deleting the affected folder(s) in "packages" so that the installer will download the missing content.  Or fixed by identifying the cause of the corruption, e.g., you may need to use different software to extract the contents of the ISO, or the ISO itself may have been corrupted.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I've copied the content of the DVD to a local drive and deleted the whole folder "packages". Now the setup is downloading all necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue resolved by getting the ISO again. Do check if your ISO is broken using its SHA.

Answer (score 0):

This means the vsgraphics_helperbits.MSI is corrupt. I was able to resolve my issue by navigating to ( \packages\vsgraphics_helper\ ) and renaming (amd64) folder to (amd6488s) and for some reason adding 888s to the folder name makes the installer reach out to the internet to download the vsgraphics that are broken in the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011 from Microsoft and then you have to import it with mmc.exe. Now uninstall all (if you allready installed) and make a clean new installation.