# Installation VS 2015 error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install VS 2015 but I get an error. What can I do? I don't understand about it.

**VsHub**
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

**Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation**
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Preview Redistributable (x86)-14.0.22310**
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Preview Redistributable (x86)-11.0.60610**
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Debug Runtime - 14.0.22310**
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Debug Runtime - 12.0.21005**
The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

Comment: It is a security problem, the installer cannot verify the digital signature on the install files.  You'll need to get your machine fixed.  Already pretty well covered by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444718/visual-studio-2013-rtm-setup-failed-the-form-specified-for-the-subject-is-not).