# Visual Studio 2017 Error while trying to Repair

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, repair

I am getting the error `the form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider VS 2017` while trying to Repair the Visual studio in my Windows 10 system.  Even, getting same error while installing the missing feature of any project. Any help on the same please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the VS 2017 completely from my system using [revo uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/) and reinstalled the VS 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you do a few things first ([**selected from this list**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130)):

1. ***Reboot***: to release any locks and do any pending file replacements.
2. ***Disk Space***: verify that you have enough.
3. ***Re-Download***: re-download the installation media (broken binary not unlikely).
4. ***Anti-Virus***: temporarily disable any anti virus during installation - after first doing a scan.
5. ***Disk Integrity***: check for disk errors.

Do all of that and try to install again please. Maybe also try the [.NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135) if you need to.

There is also this large list of suggestions to try for failing setups: [**Longer check list. See section "Generic Tricks?"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

---

***Links:***

- Here is an aging Visual Studio check list:
  [SSDT Installation fails for VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098540/ssdt-installation-fails-for-vs-2015/62147330#62147330).
- [Visual Studio 2013 RTM Setup Failed - The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444718/visual-studio-2013-rtm-setup-failed-the-form-specified-for-the-subject-is-not/19450253#19450253)

Answer (score 1):

> Visual Studio 2017 Error while trying to Repair

Thanks to **Stein** for his help.

To add more steps for this issue:

**1)** Run [this tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2970908/how-to-use-microsoft-easy-fix-solutions) to repair it.

**2)** clean %temp% folder under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp`.

**3)** check windows update and if there is any update, please update it.

**4)** disable your Anti Virus software and then Run `vs_installer.exe` as **Administrator** and make sure that your OS account is administrator.

**5)** If these do not work, I suggest you could redownload the latest `vs_installer.exe` and try to run it. or just uninstall it by **control panel** and then reinstall it and VS again.

**In addition**, you can use collect tool which is provided by Stein to share the log file with us. It usually stores under `%TEMP%vslogs.zip`. See [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/visual-studio-and-net-log-collection-utility/).

Comment: Please let me know how to share logs. Tried all the steps still getting the same issue

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z2SsoYkwY4ikDLU-naQX-ZRgCVablozN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: First, open `service.msc` and then find `Windows Management` Instrumentation, right-click it, then click `Start`. Look at the `Startup Type` and see if it says `Manual (Trigger Start)`. If it does not say that, right-click on it, click on properties and set the `Startup Type` to automatic. 2. delete  the content of `C:\Users\perryq\AppData\Local\.IdentityService`, and then run Vs installer as Administrator again.