# .exe and .msi installers does not runs on Windows 10 OS

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer

I was trying to install Node.js [node-v14.15.1-x64](https://nodejs.org/en/) on PC with Windows 10 Pro 64-bit OS, but then I found  that the problem appears  with any `.exe` and `.msi`

If I'm trying to run installer with/without administrator, I got only endless blue loading circle  icon on my screen without any error report or process in Task manager:

[image]

Hanged icon with cursor arrow does not disappears, even if I will wait for a hour, to stop it, I've to restart computer

I've followed [Stein Åsmul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129130/stein-%C3%85smul) answer, which I'm forced keep unmarked, because it seems like nothing helps yet:

1. I've re-download installation media but now I see that this happens happens to all installers.
2. I've tried turn off Windows Defender Firewall and Security Antivirus.
3. with `C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow`  Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
4. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.exe` value is `exefile`, and `exefile folder` value is `Application`, I have tried to change it with `"%1"%*`
5. in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` in `ProgrmFilesDir` value is `C:\Program Files` and in `ProgramFiles Dir (x86)` is `C:\Program Files (x86)`
6. With attempt to  `C:\WINDOWS\system32>assoc .exe=exefile` something also went wrong here, because OS  freeze, and I was forced to reboot
7. `C:\WINDOWS\system32>msiexec.exe /i :\Users\User\Desktop\New folder (1)\pycharm-community-2020.2.3.exe /L*v C:\Your.log` opens Windows Installers, which describes Display, Install, Restart and Logging Options, but I'm not sure, how to use it, to find out with this issue

**Solution:**

After removing `AVScanner.ini` form `C:\` directory problem disappeared and installation works fine

Also I have to note, that I will mark answer by [Stein Åsmul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129130/stein-%C3%85smul) because I found it useful in similar possible situation, even if it was not solution in this particular case

Any advice, guide or example would be helpful

Comment: Was the solution you found relevant for others, or was it just something machine-specific? Please report your findings if you think them relevant for the community. I have never heard of this specific issue with this package, but I have seen [similar weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509075/129130) that was hard to foresee with other packages.

Comment: As it turns out, [please have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55202408/129130). It seems I previously found that the "Event tracing (ETW)" feature in the MSI caused trouble. You should also try to launch the whole setup from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: @Stein Åsmul Hello,  sorry for that, but I was forced to remove mark from your answer,, because I found that the problem affects all .exe and .msi installers and nothing helps yet. I've edited my question, please check

Comment: The first thing I would recommend is to create a new admin account, log into that account, wait for the profile to set up correctly and then try to kick off the install using that account. This is to determine if the problem is in the user profile - which is not uncommon. One question: is this a work environment with lockdown of the machine or do you have full control. The behavior is also reminiscent of malware infection, but I see you have fun sfc.exe /scannow. Any other virus scanners? Norton? McAfee? Eset? FSecure?

Comment: How much free disk space? Did you copy the installer locally to the desktop (not network drive)?

Comment: @ Stein Åsmul Finally and accidentally  I found the reason, and I'm not quite sure about what it is AVScanner.ini, but after removing this file from C directory, now it works fine. Problem was specific and not quite clear tom me, anyway, I will mark your answer, because it contains good guide for such situation, even if not was direct solution in my particular case

Comment: That sounds slightly malware-like. Have you run any malware scanners (they can be malware themselves). Or perhaps this is that ClamAV / Clam AntiVirus software? Did you have that installed at some point?

Comment: @Stein Åsmul No, never, I don't know what is a reason of AVScanner.ini appearance

Comment: Have you run [Windows Defender in Offline mode](https://youtu.be/cLtYgAvFtD8?t=82)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225006/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-iose936).

Comment: @Stein Åsmul As well, no,  never on this device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Overall***: Do you have a screenshot? That almost sounds like a Windows Smartscreen issue?

Here are some generic setup.exe debugging suggestions:

- [Shortened setup.exe problem list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332851/129130)
- [Long setup.exe problem list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130).

***Specific Suggestions***: **`1)`** Re-download the installation media first of all. **`2)`** Then reboot and disable anti-virus scanners and try to install. **`3)`** You should also [enable logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130) and look at the log for clues. **`4)`** Try to install as a different admin users. **`5)`** Finally test on a virtual or another machine to verify the integrity of the setup file.

***Quick Logging***:

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*v C:\Your.log
```

---

- [General WiX and setup links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (section: *`"Generic Tricks? - Consumer issues"`*)
- [Smartscreen issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63136489/129130)
- [Node.js - Cannot Install it is showing an error because of .msi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201876/node-js-cannot-install-it-is-showing-an-error-because-of-msi/55202408#55202408)

Comment: Hello, I was forced to remove mark from your answer, problem affects all .exe and .msi installers. I've edited my question with actual situation and screenshot, please check